# I accidentally deleted boot option while trying to change boot order?

Tags: boot

Ok, I have an Asus x55la-hi31103j and it came with windows 10 installed but i didnt like it so i made a bootable usb wit linux ubuntu and installed that without problems. after a few days i decided to install windows 7 ultimate with bootable usb as well but it wouldnt work. it wouldn't boot on start up even when i changed the boot order.I even tried open the usb and clicking on setup..it would say could not find location to store temporary files, or something like that. Long story short while trying to figure out how to install windows 7 i accident deleted all the boot options..now my computer wont start up and i cant find a way to restore the boot options. But i did find if i put in the usb with linux loads up te grub prompt? when I put ls all it shows is (memdisk) (hdo) and (hd0,msdos1)..i tryd fallowing direction to bot from the grub prompt but i guess the disk doesnt have the file i need? is supposed to say (hd0,gpt1) or something like that....ultimately i just want to install windows 7 or if i cant re install ubuntu....help plz!!!!

Comment: You don't have to install Windows 7 to install Ubuntu.  If you are trying to install Ubuntu you are in the right forum.  If you are trying to install Windows 7 you will have to look for help installing Windows in one of the Windows forums.  Try http://superuser.com/ for Windows support.

Comment: Im trying to install ubuntu or windows, it ddoesnt matter to me i just want my laptop working again. but like i said i had ubutu installed but accidently deleted the boot options while trying to change the order now my laptop wont boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install ubuntu download the [latest version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  You should choose the 64 bit version for computers of today.  I don't know if they still make 32-bit computers.  If you have one it would be pretty old, probably more than 15 years old.

You might consider the LTS version which is supported for 5 years.  Currently the latest LTS is version 14.04.  The other versions that are not LTS are supported for 1 year.

Burn the downloaded ISO file and boot to it.  Follow the prompts for installation.  If you have data on the drive that you want to preserve (such as a Windows installation), use the option to do something else.  Pick a partition that isn't your Windows partition and install to that partition.

Once installed, the install process will provide the grub boot manager which will discover all your other Linux and Windows installed on that drive as well as any other drives that are attached to the computer and provide a boot menu to select which OS you want to load at boot.  It will default with a 10 second timeout to the latest Ubuntu installation.

**Ensuring an installation partition**

If you don't have a partition available for your fresh Ubuntu install you can create one.  When you boot to the DVD, choose the option to try Ubuntu.  Run gparted  (the partition editor) to create a new partition.  This application also has an option to change the size (shrink) a partition to make space for a new partition.

Make sure you have sufficient space to create a new partition for your Ubuntu installation.  Then click on the open (on the desktop) to install Ubuntu.  Select the newly created partition for your install drive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33454/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-i-accidentally-deleted-boot-option-while-try).